# Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run NPM angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

i have got one issue, when i run angular application. I get "program npm.cmd failed to run" in NPM. 
NPM start command please see the attachments.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please try to follow the below link and see if it helps https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6657#issuecomment-480830740

Comment: Have you tried the clean installation of NodeJS?

Comment: yes I tried the clean installation of NodeJS.